# In MS word, how do I get a two-column bulleted list in a table?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I'm not very concerned with how odd this may be. I'm just trying to make my document fairly readable given the format I'm forced to use.

I want to create a bulleted list within a table cell, but have that cell alone be two column. How can I make this happen in MS Word 2010? Below is a screenshot I've mocked up with paint of what I'd like:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I created the above screenshot, I did discover a workaround which will serve its purpose.

I right-clicked within the cell I wanted to make two-column, and selected Insert > Insert Cells... then the "Shift cells right" radio button, which resulted in the 2nd column of cells (like "something something" and "an addendum to something" in my question's picture) being resized, with no 3rd column to the right of them.

So, I selected all the 2nd column cells and resized them to cover the width of the 2nd and 3rd columns.

Finally, I clicked the 2nd column of the row which I wanted to be two-column initially, and in the ribbon, selected Table Tools > Design > Borders > Right Border to hide the border of the cells.

Not the simplest, but it got the job done!

Comment: Its the only way to do this. Either split the cell in two, or insert a second table with two cells. If you want to do it without using a table, you would end up with using a program such as publisher.